# iSeries command. Using QUAL to specify file with *FIRST and *all special values

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a command that has a member/library/file qualified field. It currently can accept `*FIRST` as the member value. I would like to add `*ALL`, but it is always telling me that it is invalid.

```
Value '*ALL      ' for parameter MBR not a valid name.


PARM       KWD(INFILE) TYPE(FILE) +    
             PROMPT('Database File Name')  


 FILE:       QUAL       TYPE(*NAME) LEN(128)                      
             QUAL       TYPE(*NAME) LEN(10) PROMPT('Library')     
             QUAL       TYPE(*NAME) LEN(10) DFT(*FIRST) +         
                           SPCVAL((*FIRST) (*ALL)) CHOICE('Name, + 
                           *FIRST, *ALL') PROMPT('Member')
```

Comment: This should compile as-is.  It does on 7.1.  Are you getting the error when you compile the command or when the command processing program executes?  If the latter, what command is *ALL not valid for?  I strongly concur with @JamesA on the common template.

Answer (score 3):

The member should not be a part of the [qualified parameter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/qual.htm).  Also the `CHOICE` parameter is optional and will be generated automatically exactly like you specified.

Here's a common template to specify a qualified file and member command:

```
 PARM       KWD(FILE) TYPE(FILE) MIN(1) +    
              PROMPT('Database File Name' 10)  
 PARM       KWD(MBR) TYPE(*NAME) LEN(10) DFT(*FIRST) SPCVAL((*FIRST) (*ALL)) +
              PROMPT('Member' 20)

 FILE:       QUAL       TYPE(*NAME) LEN(10)
             QUAL       TYPE(*NAME) LEN(10) DFT(*LIBL) SPCVAL(*LIBL) +
                          PROMPT('Library')
```

An example command line using this command would be:

```
MYCMD FILE(MYLIB/MYFILE) MBR(MYMBR)
```

Comment: I know I could make it a separate field, but then I would have to change all of the places it is used. I don't understand why it will accept *FIRST and not *ALL

Comment: @WalterD As Buck commented the command processing program appears to be returning that message not the command itself.  We would need to see the source for that program to provide more information.

Comment: You are right JamesA.  I was looking at the program that returned the messaged and it was an IBM program, but the command processor calls QCMDEXEC which executes a CHKOBJ command. That's where the error was coming from. Thanks for everyone's help!